# (Serial Column) Filtering SQL Query and shortening the results to Range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

For example, i have column tables pallet_id and serial

I would like to query them from

```
pallet_id       serial 
PA1             161
PA1             163
PA1             164
PA1             165
PA1             166
PA1             177
PA1             178
PA1             179
```

to

```
pallet_id       serial 
PA1             161-161
PA1             163-166
PA1             177-179
```

serials are incremented by 1 needs to stick as a range group

I just using Views as of the moment. If there is another way to do this without resulting to stored procedure, please do advise.

I am developing the SP now because I can't find another way.

USING MSSQL2000 or lower.. 6.5? as it says here  .. so no functions in this SQL Version. Upgrading is not an option too.

Comment: From your example it isn't too clear what logic you want to use to generate the ranges.

Comment: Im sorry. it is the range. serialization isincremented by 1. i am developing my SP to fetch and save the previous serial. if it is incremented by 1. it saves that serial and skips the rest. then skips the rest of the statement

Comment: `so no functions in this SQL Version` - why? SQL Server 2000 does support functions

Comment: its sql compat. 6.5 i thinks its lower than sql server 2000. Client doesnt want to upgrade so I am stuck with conventional methods. I am editing a report that uses a View. if I used a stored procedure like I am doing now. I would render more hours in coding the software itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table #T
(
  ID int identity,
  pallet_id varchar(8),
  serial int
)

insert into #T(pallet_id, serial)
select pallet_id, serial
from YourTable
order by pallet_id, serial

select pallet_id, min(serial) min_serial, max(serial) max_serial
from #T
group by pallet_id, serial - ID

drop table #T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f0ad/1/0)

Comment: @Sid - This is multiple statements but it does not have to be a SP just because of that.

Comment: Ok. Clearly I am not master of SQL. Can you point me in the right direction. How would I implement this to my existing View?

Comment: @Sid you can't do it in a view. If you want the code on the SQL Server side you have to use a SP but you could as well provide the code as is from the client.

Comment: Thank you. SP it is. Job was to modify his reports anyway. Just my bad luck for the extra hours. thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I'm not a fan of returning the data squished together as you've shown (161-161).  It's a function of the front-end to render data for display. The query below returns the raw ranges in separate columns, but it's easy enough to combine them if you really have to.

The solution here is for SQL Server 2005 and above, which can really start to be considered "modern". The technique it uses is grouping by differencing the row position against the id. Sequential ranges are equidistant from the ID, and hence group together nicely.

To achieve the same result in SQL Server 6.5 (!!), you'd have to pipe this through a #temp table, making use of the [ORDERING GUARANTEE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx) in the INSERT..SELECT..ORDER BY statement to produce the row numbering as [Michael has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12793992/573261) (just change the references to `@T` to `#T`).

```
-- sample table for discussion
create table tbl (
  pallet_id varchar(10),
  serial bigint);
insert tbl values
  ('PA193876',157029161),
  ('PA193876',157029163),
  ('PA193876',157029164),
  ('PA193876',157029165),
  ('PA193876',157029166),
  ('PA193876',157029177),
  ('PA193876',157029178),
  ('PA193876',157029179);

-- the query
select pallet_id, min(serial) serial_from, max(serial) serial_to
from
(
  select pallet_id, serial, grp = serial - row_number() over (order by serial)
  from tbl
) X
group by pallet_id, grp
order by pallet_id, serial_from;

-- the results
PALLET_ID   SERIAL_FROM SERIAL_TO
PA193876    157029161   157029161
PA193876    157029163   157029166
PA193876    157029177   157029179
```

e.g. `right(min(serial),10) + ' - ' + right(max(serial),10) serial_range`

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() and OVER() were not in SQL 2000